# Selecting records from a file based on keys from a second file

Tags: perl, matching

My first file looks like:

```
CHR id position                                                                                                                                                                
1 rs58108140 10583                                                                                                                                                             
1 rs189107123 10611                                                                                                                                                            
1 rs180734498 13302                                                                                                                                                            
1 rs144762171 13327                                                                                                                                                            
1 chr1:13957:D 13957
```

And my second file looks like:

```
CHR SNP POS RiskAl OTHER_ALLELE RAF logOR Pval                                                                                                                                 
10 rs1999138 110140096 T C 0.449034245446375 0.0924443 1.09e-06                                                                                                                
6 rs7741604 20839503 C A 0.138318264238111 0.127947 1.1e-06                                                                                                                    
8 rs1486006 82553172 G C 0.833130882716561 0.147456 1.12727730194884e-06
```

My script reads in the first file and stores it in an array, and then I would like to find rsIDs from column 2 of the first file that are in column 2 in the second file. I think I am having a problem with how I'm matching the expressions. Here is my script:

```
#! perl -w                                                                                                                                                                      
use strict;
use warnings;

my $F = shift @ARGV;
my @snps;
open IN, "$F";
while (<IN>) {
  next if m/CHR/;
  my @L = split;
  push @snps, [$L[0], $L[1], $L[2]] if $L[0] !~ m/[XY]/;
}
close IN;

open IN, "DIAGRAMv3sansWTCCCqc0clumpd_noTCF7L2regOrLeadOrPlt1em6clumps-     CHR_SNP_POS_RiskAl_OtherAl_RAF_logOR_Pval.txt";
while (<IN>) {
  my @L = split;
  next if m/CHR/;

  foreach (@snps) {
    next if ($L[0] != ${$_}[0]);

    # if not on same chromosome
    if ($L[0] = ${$_}[0]) {

      # if on same chromosome
      if ($L[1] =~ ${$_}[1]) {
        print "$L[0] $L[1] ${$_}[2]\n";
        last;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Store the data in a hash with the column 2 as the key.

Comment: Post your desired output from the sample data that you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to correspond to your description. You are comparing both the first and second columns of the file rather than just the second.

The main problems are:

- You use `$L[0] = ${$_}[0]` to compare the first columns. This will do an *assigmment* instead of a comparison. You should use `$L[0] == ${$_}[0]` instead or, better, `$L[0] == $_->[0]`
- You use `$L[1] =~ ${$_}[1]` to compare the second columns. This will check whether `${$_}[1]` is a *substring* of `$L[1]`. You could use anchors like `$L[1] =~ /^${$_}[1]$/` but it's much better to just do a string comparison as `$L[1] eq $_->[1]`

The easiest way is to read the second file *first* so as to build a list of values that you want included from the first file. I have written it so that it does what your code looks like it's supposed to do, i.e. match the first *two* columns.

That would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($f1, $f2) = @_;

my %include;
open my $fh2, '<', $f2;
while (<$fh2>) {
  my @fields = split;
  my $key = join '|', @fields[0,1];
  ++$include{$key};
}
close $fh2;

open my $fh1, '<', $f1;
while (<$fh1>) {
  my @fields = split;
  my $key = join '|', @fields[0,1];
  print "@fields[0,1,2]\n" if $include{$key};
}
close $fh1;
```

**output**

Unfortunately your choice of sample data doesn't include *any* records in the first file that have matching keys in the second, so there is no output!

---

**Update**

This is a corrected version of your own program. It should work, but it is far more efficient and concise to use hashes, as above

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($filename) = @ARGV;
my @snps;
open my $in_fh, '<', $filename;
<$in_fh>; # Discard header line
while (<$in_fh>) {
  my @fields = split;
  push @snps, \@fields unless $fields[0] =~ /[XY]/;
}
close $in_fh;

open $in_fh, '<', 'DIAGRAMv3sansWTCCCqc0clumpd_noTCF7L2regOrLeadOrPlt1em6clumps-     CHR_SNP_POS_RiskAl_OtherAl_RAF_logOR_Pval.txt';
<$in_fh>; # Discard header line
while (<$in_fh>) {
  my @fields = split;
  for my $snp (@snps) {
    next unless $fields[0] == $snp->[0] and $fields[1] eq $snp->[1];
    print "$fields[0] $fields[1] $snp->[2]\n";
    last;
  }
}
close $in_fh;
```